# Webpack i18n with plurals

Tags: internationalization, webpack, gettext

Is there any way to build properly webpack bundles with different languages, like `i18n-webpack-plugin`, but supporting plural forms? Something like gettext.

For example:

- 1 girl  - 1 dívka
- 2 girls - 2 dívky
- 10 girls - 10 dívek

Comment: in pure `i18n-webpack-plugin` there is no support plural functionality  https://github.com/webpack/i18n-webpack-plugin/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jed-webpack-plugin

It helps you to make multiple bundles for each language.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need.